# Print a vector of strings

Tags: string, matlab, char

I have a double vector, i.e., `x = [1 2 3 4]`. There is a corresponding string for each element in `x`, for example, `1`:`'4'`, `2`:`'16'`, `3`:`'4+'`, and `4`:`'100-'`, quite random corresponse. Now given any order of the elements in `x`, I want to print the corresponding string in MATLAB.

For example, if `input = [2 1 3 4]`, I want to print `"The output is 16 4 4+ 100-"` in MATLAB with space between these strings. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: how are your strings/string stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are your strings stored? I'm assuming like this:

```
str = {'4', '16', '4+', '100-'}
input = [2 1 3 4]
```

In that case you have a few options e.g.

```
sprintf('The output is %s %s %s %s', str{input})
```

or else

```
['The output is ', strjoin(str(input))]
```